# Is there embedded DB with PL/SQL support and Java API?

Tags: java, plsql, embedded-database

I'm looking for embedded db with Java API for testing purposes.
Also i need pl/sql support because we use oracle in production and migrations are written in pl/sql.

I want to test my DAO objects and i need to create db in memory in process of unit test using migration scripts.

Now we use HSQLDB but it does't support pl/sql.

Can you recommend anything?

Answer (score 7):

According to the wikipedia page about PL/SQL, the databases supporting PL/SQL are Oracle and DB2:

- [Embedded DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.uprun.doc/doc/c0021588.htm)
- [Embedded Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/embedded/index.html)

If these don't suit you, there's nothing else. PL/SQL is a creation of Oracle, so it's not expected to be widely spread.

Comment: In-memory doesn't mean embedded. I mean i need to have dedicated instance of db somewhere. But i want to create an instance in runtime.

Comment: Thanks. will take a look. first look: db2 has only c++ api. oracle's site is full of unuseful information. still search for docs about solution.

Comment: I found Berkley DB. But it supports plsql only with 3rd-party modules (also has only c++ api). I think i want impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing Oracle XE on your local developer workstation and Continuous Integration server. Then connect with the SYS as SYSDBA or SYSTEM user to create your schema(s) before executing your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org)'s pl/sql extensively.  It has an embedded server you can access through JDBC.