# SQL Server local database file equivalent in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I've created an app with a local database incorporated in the folder app using C# and SQL Server.

I'm doing a Java app and want to know if there's an Oracle database that can be used as local (so that I can place the app folder in a USB and then it can be accessed in any computer). I also want to use my PL/SQL know-how.

Comment: Lots, I believe the [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) can, but I know for sure that [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) can run in "file only" or "single user" modes.  So can SQLLite if you're not worried about "pure" Java database engines

Comment: Are those DBs use PL/SQL, stored procedures, functions, etc.?

Comment: Check the links, I think you'll be surprised

Comment: You could also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226746/is-there-embedded-db-with-pl-sql-support-and-java-api

Comment: Thanks! Embedded Oracle is the one I'm looking for.